# Как получить прямую ссылку на изображение ВКонакте по его ID?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня есть ссылка на запись с фотографией — [фото](https://vk.com/rostislav_dugin?z=photo213737404_316668269%2Falbum213737404_0%2Frev)

Как получить прямую ссылку на изображение вида `https://pp.vk.me/c320525/v320525404/5502/wDguXeHdmZk.jpg` для загрузки *Universal Image Loader'ом*?

---

P.S. В VK Api я не нашел нужного метода для получения ссылки на фото по его id (213737404_316668269), поэтому идеи, кроме как получать ссылку напрямую — нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В доках говорится, что надо использовать метод `photos.getById`:

> https://vk.com/dev/photos.getById?params[photos]=213737404_316668269&params[extended]=1&params[photo_sizes]=0&params[v]=5.52

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. итоговый запрос такой:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getById?photos=213737404_316668269
```

Ответ такой:

```
{"response":[{"pid":316668269,"aid":-6,"owner_id":213737404,"src":"http:\/\/cs320525.vk.me\/v320525404\/5501\/Js1OGe3cJMs.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/cs320525.vk.me\/v320525404\/5502\/wDguXeHdmZk.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/cs320525.vk.me\/v320525404\/5500\/FfVY13pbe3I.jpg","width":600,"height":600,"text":"","created":1388256629,"post_id":972}]}
```

Comment: Так вот, что означает "возвращает информацию о фотографиях"... Спасибо :).